# How to use variables in decimal pipe in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to create a decimal pipe for number formatting with dynamic variables in angular 2

Example for decimal pipe - number_expression | number[:digitInfo]  where digitInfo is a string which has a following format: 
{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}

I want the {minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits} to be set through my code

Answer (score 0):

Write your own pipe, this is a sample from official docs:

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
/*
 * Raise the value exponentially
 * Takes an exponent argument that defaults to 1.
 * Usage:
 *   value | exponentialStrength:exponent
 * Example:
 *   {{ 2 |  exponentialStrength:10}}
 *   formats to: 1024
*/
@Pipe({name: 'exponentialStrength'})
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, exponent: string): number {
    let exp = parseFloat(exponent);
    return Math.pow(value, isNaN(exp) ? 1 : exp);
  }
}
```

**Let's write the DecimalNumberPipe**

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'decimalNumber'})
export class DecimalNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, decimal: string): number {
    let dec = value - Math.floor(value)
    return dec;// write your formatting code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! How can I return the decimal value based on user locale in angular 2? using toLocaleString() recommended?